# How can I configure Lightroom to use the JPEG from the camera for previewing?

Tags: lightroom, raw, jpeg

I take photos in both RAW and JPEG.

Sometimes I might apply a color style on the JPEG in-camera, but when I import the photos in Lightroom, only the RAW is visible.

Can I somehow configure Lightroom, to use the JPEG for the preview and not the RAW version?

Comment: Are you using the most current version of Lightroom CC or some other version? If so, what particular version?

Answer (score 2):

About the best you can do in LR is to check "Treat JPEG files next to raw files as separate photos" under 'Preferences--->General' and view each separately.

'Photo--->Stacking--->Auto-Stack by Capture Time' will auto arrange each JPEG/Raw set next to each other.

Comment: Thank you. That seams to do the trick. But unfortunately there's now way to tell Lightroom to use the JPEG version on top of the RAW when stacking :( So, I think I might give up.